# Security Namespace Configuration in Spring 3.2.4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring 3.2.4 application and I want to add spring security, so I add the jar **spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE** and **spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar** in the project

I want to include

```
<http auto-config="true">  
  <!-- enable csrf protection -->
  <csrf/>
</http>
```

in the `applicationContext.xml` file , I also included the Security Namespace

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
```

But I got this error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
```

Comment: You need also `spring-config` next to that use the versionless schemas from spring instead of the versioned ones. Finally you have declared a `security` namespace not a `http` namespace. Either rename `security` to `http` or use `security:` instead of `http:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">


    <security:http auto-config="true">    
      <!-- enable csrf protection -->
      <security:csrf/>
    </security:http>
```